# A Final Twins Puzzle: Twelve Days Difference?

Tags: knowledge, time

> Inspired by @athin's [One More Twin Puzzle: Four Days Difference?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58512/one-more-twin-puzzle-four-days-difference)

After reading @athin's question, I was inspired to ask my own puzzle club about their birthdays. One of the members, Ethan, surprised me:

> "My birthday was just two days ago. But you'll never believe this - one of my great-great-… well, I'm not sure how far back it is, but my one of my direct ancestors was one of a pair of twins, and their birthdays were 12 and 24 days ago."

Is it possible Ethan is telling the truth? How?

<sup>NB: the people whose birthdays were 12 and 24 days ago were twins of each other</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it *is* possible!

> In 1752, [11 days were skipped from the calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html) to realign the Gregorian and Julian calendars. If one was born just before this skip and another was born after, then they could be twins born 12 days apart.

Comment: [Relevant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49102/31394) (link target is a spoiler for this puzzle, naturally).

Answer (score 8):

*Beaten by Deusovi by 1 minute, well played, well played...*

Answer

> Your ancestors were born the 2nd (just before midnight) and 14th (just after midnight) of September in the year 1752.

Why ?

> Because the [Gregorian calendar at that time skipped 11 days !](http://mentalfloss.com/article/51370/why-our-calendars-skipped-11-days-1752)

Comment: Dammit @Deusovi ! 1 minute too late :(
I'll definitely second this post : https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/should-we-ban-deusovi-from-puzzle-solving/6160#6160